# efficiently stream large file (video) from go server

Tags: video, go, server, stream

I am implementing video stream server in Go.
I am currently using standard [fileserver](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) but I am unsure if it is efficient with large files (4GB+).

Is there a way to efficiently serve large file in Go?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "efficient" so I will assume you mean that large files are streamed and not buffered.

The standard `http.FileServer` eventually writes data using [the `serveContent` function](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L148), which requires an `io.ReadSeeker` as the contents (fortunately files are just that).

The contents is then copied using `io.Copy`, which in the general case (though probably not your common case, see below) means [`copyBuffer`](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go#L374). will use a 32KB buffer.

Therefore, assuming the implementation of `http.ResponseWriter` does not buffer its input ([it doesn't](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L394), see also [chunked writer](https://golang.org/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go)), memory utilization should be constant.

However when the writer supports a `ReadFrom` method, [`io.Copy` will use that instead](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go#L382). Because `http.response` (the standard  implementation of `ResponseWriter` interface) [implements the ReadFrom method](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L545), it'll be used instead of `copyBuffer`. This implementation in turn will try use the `sendfile` system call when possible (as is the case for `os.File`), which is a stronger meaning of efficient (the data doesn't have to go through the process memory space at all, so about as good as it gets).

In other words, I think it's reasonable to say that the built in `net/http` package already supports efficient streaming of large files.